# sending email through mailgun

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun

I am trying to add a mailgun contact form to my website using nodejs express and mailgun-js. But somehow I cannot get it to work. My api key and domain are good since I tested them with the sample code on mailgun-js's official github page. So I am wondering if there is anything wrong with the following pieces of code. (routing and everything else works perfectly)

./models/mailer.js

```
            var api_key = 'xxxxxxx';
            var domain = 'xxxxxxxx';

            var Mailgun = require('mailgun-js');

            exports.sendOne = function (locals,callback) {

                console.log(locals);
                var mailgun = new Mailgun({apiKey: api_key,domain:domain});

                var data = {
              from: 'xxxxxx',
              to: 'myemail@hotmail.com',
              subject: 'Hello World',
              text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
            };

                mailgun.message().send(data,function (err,body) {
                        if(err) return callback(err);
                        console.log('message sent');
                        callback(null,body);
                });
            };
```

./controllers/contactCtrl.js

```
    var mailer = require('../models/mailer');

    exports.contact = function (req,res,next) {
        res.render('contact');
    };


    exports.receiveMessage = function (req,res,next) {

            mailer.sendOne(req.body,function (err,body) {
                if(err) return next(err);
                console.log(body);
                res.send({message:'Your message has been successfully sent'});
            });

    };
```

Thanks A Lot   :)

Comment: looks good. what breaks

Comment: em....I just didn't get the email and on the front end I didn't get the message 'Your message has been successfully sent'

Comment: Have you verified that your domain is in Active state at mailgun. Without it sending mails will not be possible. Did u try to debug it, the code seems ok.

Debug the code and see if its even reaching to the final line of code

Comment: I am using the mailgun sandbox domain and it is active.                               Yeah I did try to debug it and it did get to the mailgun.message().send() portion. Emm...is there any good debugging tool I can use? Sorry I am pretty new to nodejs and I had been using console.log for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

mailgun.message()

You are missing a "s". It should be mailgun.messages()